# How appropriate is the use of the statement fflush(stdin)?

Tags: c, gets

To read multi-word strings, I have been using the gets() function. The behaviour of the `gets()` function is unpredictable to me and I use the statement `fflush(stdin)` before every `gets()` statement to avoid issues. Is using this statement this way appropriate? What can be an alternative approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fgets() instead of gets(): https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309760/1758762

As everyone else said, the canonical alternative to gets() is fgets() specifying stdin as the file stream.

```
char buffer[BUFSIZ];

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
{
    ...process line of data...
}
```

What no-one else yet mentioned is that gets() does not include the newline but fgets() does. So, you might need to use a wrapper around fgets() that deletes the newline:

```
char *fgets_wrapper(char *buffer, size_t buflen, FILE *fp)
{
    if (fgets(buffer, buflen, fp) != 0)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(buffer);
        if (len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '\n')
            buffer[len-1] = '\0';
        return buffer;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But if BUFSIZ is not known beforehand and I create a string using a char pointer, how can fgets() be used?

Comment: BUFSIZ is just a constant to be define like #define BUFSIZ 255 or something else ...

Answer (score 3):

`fflush` only flush output streams.

If you want to *flush* stdin, keep reading until you get `EOF`, something like:

```
int i;
while (((i = getchar()) != '\n') && (i != EOF));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scanf statement with appropriate Regular expression.

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
```

or maybe a fgets statement.
`fgets(str, sizeof(str),stdin));`